# Pimcore newsletter

Tags: php, linux, pimcore

I have problem to execute background process. That process is about sending email to newsletter subscribers.
When I make it started, it returns default message like "The emails are being sent in background blah blah..." but it never finish. None of subscribers receives email.

By digging in log files I found the command that supposes to be used for beginning operation mentioned above.

```
/usr/bin/nohup /usr/bin/nice -n 19 /usr/bin/php /%absolute_path_to_web_root%/pimcore/cli/console.php internal:newsletter-send 'newsletter_de' 'http://hostname' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!
```

Status in newsletter dashboard is like:
[in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkqfV.png) and it never changes.

Note: Testing the newsletter works perfectly.

My questions are:

1. What could be cause of problem? Linux, Pimcore app or something else?
2. Did anyone meet such problem?
3. If yes, did he solve it and how if yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. Background process runs fine but output file location is not writable for user that runs web server so I couldn't read error report.